# Approximation of product of Bernoulli with different proportions

Tags: probability, approximation, bayesian, bernoulli-numbers, beta-function

I want to update a variable $Y$ with Beta (uniform for simplicity, $Y \sim U(0, 1)$) distribution, with Bernoulli information each period... But each period the proportion parameter of the Bernoulli varies.
I have a product of Bernoulli densities with different proportions $p_i$. (success $x_i = 1$ or failure $x_i = 0$).

It looks like this:

$ f(y|x_i) \propto  \Pi_{i=1}^{n} (p_i y)^{x_i}(1-p_i y)^{1-x_i} = (p_1 y)^{x_1} (1-p_1 y)^{1-x_1} ... \cdot \ (p_n y)^{x_n} (1-p_n y)^{1-x_n}$
where $y \in [0, 1]$

I would like to approximate it by:
$(Py)^{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i} (1-Py)^{n - \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}$ where $P$ would be a function of $(p_1, p_2, ..., p_n, \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i, n)$.
I need such an approximation because I would need to summarize the information in all the $p_i$ in a small number of parameters.
If needed, I can use at most two parameters, something like:
$(P_1 y)^{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i} (1-P_2y)^{n - \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}$ where $P_1$ and $P_2$ would be a function of $(p_1, p_2, ..., p_n, \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i, n)$.

I do not have a good math background, is there any good analytical approximation for this that I am not aware of? Or do I have to solve it numerically ?

---

Edit: Partial solution.

As suggested by Jim in the comment below, I simply have the two closed forms:

$P_1 = (\Pi^n_{i=1} p_i^{x_i})^{1/\sum x_i}$
$P_2 = \frac{1}{y}(1 - (\Pi^n_{i=1} (1 - y p_i)^{1-x_i})^{1/(n - \sum x_i)})$

From this, I can build recursive formulation: from a given $P_1$, knowing the present $x_i$ and $p_i$, I can build the next $P_1$.

However, it does not work as well for $P_2$. As you can see, $P_2$ depends on $y$. So I actually have a distribution of $P_2$... While I would like to gather all the information about $P_2$ in ONE value. This is not feasible (at least I did not find any solution). However, $P_2 \times y$ seems to be a quasi-linear function of $y$: I think I will save the coefficient of the linear regression as my coefficient of information $P_2$ (by default). This is the best approximation I can think of, except if any of you have a better idea.

Comment: What is $y$ ? You haven´t defined it.

Comment: $Y$ is my variable prior uniform density, and 'updated posterior density' $f(Y=y | x_i)$.

Comment: You can get $P_1$ exactly with $P_1 = {\left({\prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{x_i}}\right)} ^{1/{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}}$.  (Sorry, I just can't get the right parenthesis to show at the end of the product.)

Comment: And you can get $P_2$ exactly, too.  (But both of these exact solutions depend on knowing $x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n$, too.)

Comment: I do not want to use information about $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ independently. However I will have information about their sum  $\sum^n_{i=1} x_i$ and $n$. So I cannot use the formulation you are using this is why I think I need some kind of approximation.

Comment: In fact, I was thinking about it, I was dumb: I can use information in all $x_i$ independently. Well, I cannot really, but the thing is, my program is recursive, so if from 1 period $P_1$ I can obtain the next period $P$, it works. So basically, with this $P_1$ it works (from a previous $P_1$, knowing the sum $x_i$, $n$ and the present $x_i$ I can recover the next $P_1$. 
I am trying to derive $P_2$ the same way now, see if it can work there too. 
Thanks a lot anyway, it will allow me to avoid weird numerical approximation schemes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your endgame is to get the posterior density for y, I'm not understanding why you need an approximation when you can get the exact posterior density for any particular set of data.  Here's how to do it using *Mathematica*:

```
(* Data *)
n = 10;
p = {2/10, 3/10, 222/1000, 15/100, 19/100, 4/10, 44/100, 21/100, 34/100, 1/10};
x = {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1};

(* Constant of integration *)
const = Integrate[Expand[Product[y^x[[i]] p[[i]]^x[[i]] (1 - y p[[i]])^(1 - x[[i]]), {i, n}]], {y, 0, 1}]
(* 200262223/78125000000000 *)

(* Posterior density for y *)
f[y_] := (1/const) Product[y^x[[i]] p[[i]]^x[[i]] (1 - y p[[i]])^(1 - x[[i]]), {i, n}]

(* Plot density *)
Plot[f[y], {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{Style["Density", Large], ""}, {Style["y", Large],""}}]

(* Check on density integrating to 1 *)
Integrate[f[y], {y, 0, 1}]
(* 1 *)
```

[image: Posterior density]

Comment: In fact I am in a dynamic program with information updating. I will have a value function written recursively, with information as state parameters. The thing is, for my problem to be solvable, I need to have a low number of state parameters (if I used updating of a gaussian law, I would have the mean and the standard deviation as parameters to describe the whole thing). 
Here, I cannot afford to save every past realization of $x_i$ and $p_i$ in the parameters, the problem becomes untractable. That's why I need to find a way to reduce the dimensionality.

Comment: OK.  I get it now.  I'll think more about this.  But...are there any patterns to the $p_i$ values?  Do they arise from some known functional form?  And how far off can you be from the "true" posterior density?  And how might you characterize what "far off" or "close enough" means for your particular application?

Comment: $p_i$ are dependent on the choice in the maximization of my dynamic program (they are the probabilities that a normally distributed variable is inferior to my choice). The choice depends on the information set itself. So the $p_i$ should always be quite close to each other (depends on my shocks), but no identified pattern a priori (can be increasing, then decreasing, etc.). 
Concerning how far I want to be, I do not really have an order of value, what I want is for the mean of the approximated process to be close (let's say 0.01 at most) to the true posterior mean.